# SMS can't be sent using GSM module SIM900A

Tags: module, arduino, gsm

I am trying to send a SMS using GSM SIM900A. But there is no compilation error and other interference there.

The code is executed properly but SMS isn't sent to the number mentioned in the code.

```cpp
#include <TinyGPS.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);
SoftwareSerial SIM900A(7, 8);

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  SIM900A.begin(9600);
  pinMode(6, INPUT);
}

void loop() {

  bool state = digitalRead(6);
  if (state == HIGH) {

    SIM900A.println("AT+CMGF=1");
    delay(1000);
    SIM900A.println("AT+CMGS=\"+8801679388394\"\r");
    delay(1000);
    
    SIM900A.println("Alert I need help....Asheesh ,Battalion No. 1233456 ");
    SIM900A.println((char)26);
    
    delay(10000);

  }
  else {
    delay(2000);
  }
}
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GSM SIM900A only supports 2G SIM card.At first make sure that you are using a 2G SIM.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check that your SIM900A has been initialized properly. You also need to check whether GSM module has detected the SIM card. Usually this is indicated by an onboard LED that blinks after every **3 seconds**. 
The following code is to send sms to a user.

```
void sendSMS()
{
   SIM900A.println("AT+CMGF=1");
   delay(1000);

   SIM900A.println("AT+CMGS=\"+8801679388394\"\r");
   delay(1000); 

   SIM900A.print("Hello");
   delay(1000);

   SIM900A.println((char)26);     // sends ctrl+z end of message 
   delay(5000);
}
```

Before trying this code, check that you’re connected to the network using `AT+COPS?`. Once you open a serial monitor, make sure that ‘**Both NL & CR**’ option is selected!

Comment: The onboard led blinks after every 3 seconds. I think GSM module has detected the SIM card successfully. I tried by replacing your code. It still didn't work

Comment: Read the following article very carefully and test AT commands one by one. https://lastminuteengineers.com/sim900-gsm-shield-arduino-tutorial/